# (C++) Break; and return; don't work in my for() function

Tags: c++

So I have a for() function where I loop all players in the vector and if a player or multiple players have invalid coordinates, the function will print an error. The problem is that instead of an error, i get 2 for the same player. I tried using return; and break; but it doesn't seem to be working..
Any help? Here is the code:

```
for(unsigned int k = 0; k < playerVec.size(); k++)
{
    if(playerVec[k].xPos + playerVec[k].yPos >
       worldObj.worldWidth + worldObj.worldHeight)
    {
        // Invalid coordinates
        std::cout << "ERROR | Player \"" << playerVec[k].name << "\" has invalid "
        "coordinates! Spawning operation aborted!" << std::endl;

        // Exit from function
        return;
    }

    else
    {
        // Spawn player
        worldObj.world[playerVec[k].yPos][playerVec[k].xPos] =
        playerVec[k].appearance;
    }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"it doesn't seem to be working"*? Please provide a [mcve] and explain what you see during debugging that seems wrong

Comment: Can you show the content of the playerVec and the output of your for-loop (what is printed)?

Comment: @pallgeuer The playerVec contains 2 players and what i noticed is that if the last player from the vector has wrong coords, it will only show an error but if the first player has wrong coords, it will give two errors.

Comment: Is it possible that this code (the entire function that contains this for-loop) is executed twice by surrounding code in the case that 'return' exits the function early?

Comment: _I have a for() function_ is ambiguous, is your for loop in a function, or are you calling the loop a function? If you just want to exit the for loop, use break  https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/break-statement-cc/

Comment: `for` is not a function - it's a statement. As such, it cannot stand on its own but may be used in a function body only.